# Why an inline-block container doesn't collapse when contains only floated items?

Tags: css, css-float

In this layout there are 3 boxes that I'm putting in a row applying `float: left;` to each one of them.
The boxes are inside 2 other containers. Normally, these containers collapse, because that's what happens when the content is only made by floated items.
Changing the `display` property of the 2 containers to `inline-block`, though, avoid the collapsing.

Why is that?

Also: I'm well aware of the fact that we shouldn't use float for putting elements in a row and that the modern and correct approach would be to use `flexbox` or `grid`, but I've stumbled on this by accident and was curious to understand why

```css
.container {
  background: tomato;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.box {
  border: 3px solid black;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.box-1 {
  background: aquamarine; 
}
.box-2 {
  background: yellowgreen; 
}

.box-3 {
  background: pink; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
  <li class="box box-1"></li> 
  <li class="box box-2"></li> 
  <li class="box box-3"></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `inline-block` generate a block formatting context

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as **inline-blocks**, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new **block formatting contexts** for their contents. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)</sup>

and you can read in [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context):

> Formatting contexts affect layout, but typically, we create a new block formatting context for the positioning and clearing floats rather than changing the layout, because an element that establishes a new block formatting context will:
>
> - **contain internal floats.**
> - exclude external floats.
> - suppress margin collapsing.

Comment: thanks! I was aware of the concert of formatting context, but had no idea that inline-block created one